# How can I change the GUI controls' properties programatically in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, properties, matlab-guide

As the question title says, I don't know how to change programatically the properties of the different controls that come with the Matlab GUI. Let's say that I have an edit control, whose String property I want to modify. What code do I write?

I researched both the on-line and the local help, but I didn't find anything satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example:

```
h = uicontrol('style', 'edit', 'string', 'initial string'); %// create object
set(h, 'string', 'changed string'); %// change object property
```

(The second line could be part of the another object's [callback](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html) function, which causes the first object's string to change.)

As an alternative, if you don't have a handle to the object, you can assign the object a `'tag'` (you can do that with [GUIDE](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-guide-gui-example.html)) and then locate the object by that tag using [`findobj`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html):

```
uicontrol('style', 'edit', 'string', 'initial string', 'tag','e123'); %// or use GUIDE
set(findobj('tag', 'e123'), 'string', 'changed string');
```

Comment: Thank you. How does this code modify if my control is already been created through the GUI interface?

Comment: You can use tags (which you asign with GUIDE); see edit.